# How to turn command output to a live status update?

Tags: linux, bash, zsh

I am curious if there's a tool or an easy way to continually execute a certain command in given intervals, and reprint its output into same place on the screen.

The example that prompted me to think about it is 'dropbox-cli status'. Manually executed:

```
$> dropbox-cli status
Syncing (6,762 files remaining)
Indexing 3,481 files...
$> dropbox-cli status
Syncing (5,162 files remaining)
Indexing 2,681 files...
```

I am looking for:

```
$> tracker --interval=1s "dropbox-cli status"
Syncing (6,743 files remaining)
Indexing 3,483 files
```

The imaginary command 'tracker' would block and the two output lines would be continually reprinted over every second, rather than creating an appending log output.

Comment: I think you're looking for the `watch` command.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [`watch`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/watch)

```
watch -n1 dropbox-cli status
```

Specify the time in seconds with param `-n`.